# MASM x86 Computing the sum of odd numbers Fibonacci sequence between 0 and 1000000

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, fibonacci

I need to make a masm program that adds all odd numbers of the fibonacci sequence between 0 to 1000000. The following code is all I have so far. When I go into debug and look at the ecx register which is where the sum is being stored, it looks like its not adding them right. The sum in the ecx register go 1,4,9, etc, but it should be 1,2,5,10,23, etc. The final result should be 1089154. When I try printing out the sum in the terminal it prints "+1000000" which isn't right. Please help!

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode:DWORD
INCLUDE irvine32.inc
.data
    first_num DWORD 0   
    second_num DWORD 1  
    odd_sum DWORD 0     

.code
main PROC
    
    mov eax, 0      
    mov ebx, 1      
    mov ecx, 0      

    
    fibonacci_loop:
        add eax, ebx        
        test eax, 1     
        jz skip_add         
        add ecx, eax        
    skip_add:
        cmp eax, 1000000    
        jl fibonacci_loop   

    mov odd_sum, ecx
    call writeint


    INVOKE ExitProcess, 0
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: `add eax, ebx` alone doesn't in a loop doesn't compute the Fibonacci sequence, just an increment by 1 every time.  Maybe you want `xadd eax, ebx` or `xchg eax, ebx` / `add eax, ebx` or something.

Comment: Or since the classic Fibonacci(0,1) alternates odd/even after it gets started (past the 1, 1 near the start), `add ebx, eax` / `add eax,ebx` to do 2 Fibonacci iterations per loop iteration, then unconditional `add ecx, eax`.  But then you'd have to check for off-by-one errors and make sure you started in a way that would have the odd value in EAX, even values in EBX.

Comment: @PeterCordes Fibonacci(0,1) goes even-odd-odd-even-odd-odd and so on, so unrolling three iterations could be an option (you'd still have to check for the end-condition somehow).

Comment: @Evan I suggest to first make sure that you generate all Fibonacci numbers correctly (either print out every number, or step through your code with a debugger). You are currently summing up the odd numbers (the partial sums of which are the square numbers).

Comment: @chtz: Thanks.  The confirmation bias was strong when I looked and saw odd and even numbers, without really looking at any sequence of more than 2!  For the termination condition when unrolling by 3, you might allow overshoot and work backwards using numbers still in registers to correct it.